# Bitcoin wallet taking days to receive coins

Tags: receiving

Previously withdrawing bitcoins from Intersango has only taken 24 hours.  This particular transaction has taken several days and I still haven't received the bitcoins.  I withdrew the coins from Intersango but they haven't been received by my wallet yet.  Does it make a difference that shortly after I withdrew the coins from Intersango I encrypted my wallet? Does it make a difference that it is currently 'locked,' if so how do I unlock it to recieve coins? Please somebody help this is really worrying me!

Answer (score 3):

Intersango has been having a problem with their wallet recently, as described in [this forum post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=63877.msg1037215#msg1037215).  [Another post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=63877.msg1038709#msg1038709) claims that:

> this was triggered by someone spamming the wallet with a very larger
>   number of small transactions

Encrypting your wallet won't make any difference to whether you receive the bitcoins or not.  You only need to "unlock" the wallet to spend coins (or to top out your pool of unused addresses).

You can check at http://blockchain.info/address/*1youraddresshere* to see whether the coins have been sent yet.  If they show up there but not in your wallet then it's an issue with your wallet.

Comment: Did you receive the coins yet?  A poster in the thread ( https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=63877.msg1041600#msg1041600 ) says that he contacted support and received his coins immediately.